# Android JSON Parsing (Jackson)

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, jackson

I've read a bunch of different articles, comparations and tutorials that are using different JSON-Libraries for parsing (and creating) JSON into Java Objects. Anyway I think that I've got the facts right cause I've decided to use the JSON library called **Jackson.**

GSON is simple and robust but way to slow acording to me. So I decided to actually try this Jackson thing out but, it seems like the parsing is a little bit more confusing here than with GSON.

The data-type of the value that I want to parse is simply an **Boolean**.

*This is what the JSON that I'm trying to parse looks like:*

```
{"FooResult":true}
```

So what I actually need help with is selecting the value from the key `FooResult` and then parse its value into an Boolean.

*This Is what I've done so far:*

```
String json = getString(request);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(json, Boolean.class);
```

But this code obviously gives me an error cause I haven't selected that it is the `FooResult` key that I'm interested in reading & parsing into an Boolean.

Comment: mapper.readValue(json, Boolean.class); -- This won't work, because the JSON does not represent a Boolean type/value.  The JSON is an object with a single property, and that property is a Boolean (or boolean) type value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a new class like this:

```
class MyClass {
   public boolean FooResult;
}
```

And use this code to load the data:

`MyClass myObject = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);`

Then you can access the value with `myObject.FooResult`

Comment: Unfortunatly this ain't working. I get an JsonMappingException which are telling me that the Jackson library couldn't deserialize the object for me as a Bean.

Comment: Simon's answer is correct.  Note, it's not necessary to define the FooResult field as a public member.

Comment: Yes, it actually even works to define it as a private member, thanks to Jackson using Reflection to read/write the values. I usually put these classes in their own Java files, but using static as @Parek suggested below can also work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is lame. Even lamer when I rethink about it. The problem the whole time have been that the class of the object that you want to parse needs to be **static**. I've tried what Simon suggested like four or five times before I even posted this question today but the problem all time was that the class wasn't **static**.

So now it finally works.

```
static class FooClass
{  
    public boolean FooResult; 
}
```

And for the parsing process.

```
String json = getString(request);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
FooClass fooClass = null;
try 
{
    fooClass = mapper.readValue(json, FooClass.class);
}
boolean result = fooClass.FooResult;
```

Comment: "the class of the object that you want to parse needs to be static" -- That's not correct.  I guess that you're declaring the target class as an inner class of something else.  Maybe you just need to move the FooClass class declaration outside of the declaration of any other class.  As I recall, Gson does handle inner class (de)serialization a little differently than Jackson.  So, maybe that's why the Gson solution you had didn't work exactly the same way as with Jackson.

Comment: FWIW, the reason that non-static inner classes do not work is that they must get a reference to an instance of surrounding class ("implicit this pointer"). And this is typically not available during deserialization; at least in your example there is no surrounding POJO. In theory one could make it work by passing `null` as parent reference I guess... which might cause other odd issues, but at least would deserialize.